# Laravel 7 Passport : blocked by CORS policy

Tags: cors, axios, laravel-passport, laravel-7

When I make the following **axios** request to my **Laravel 7.3 Passport** API:

```
let url = 'http://laravel.test/oauth/token'

let params = {
  client_id:  4,
  client_secret: 'FBkMiLI8ecdb4A8OhLRDGS1SasZP5NT7i9Qpp7bP',
  grant_type: 'password',
  username: 'me@home.com',
  password: '1qaz@WSX',
  scope: '*'
}

let headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
  }

axios.post(url, params, headers)
.then(response => {
      this.access_token = response['data']['access_token'];
      this.get_users_data()
  })
.catch(response => {
// eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log(response)
});
```

I get this error in my javascript console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://laravel.test/oauth/token' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Also, `config/cors.php` in Laravel 7.3 is configured to allow anything (by default):

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

What's wrong in my request ?

Comment: did you find a solution? Please, reply to my question as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422229/any-reason-why-pre-build-cors-policy-configuration-not-functioning-in-laravel-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing's wrong with your request. Your API resource has a [CORS policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) which restricts what domains may access the resource. The error you're getting is telling you that the resource does not have a CORS header allowing access from the calling domain.

You need to set the CORS policy to whitelist your domain: `http://localhost:3000`. You may find this article, [Handling CORS in a Laravel Application](https://freek.dev/948-handling-cors-in-a-laravel-application), helpful:

> Recently we released laravel-cors. This package can add the necessary CORS headers of your Laravel app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I checked the `config/cors.php` in Laravel and it seems to me that it's configured to allow any URL. I've just updated my post regarding Laravel's CORS config.

Comment: Is it perhaps that your request URL is not under `'paths' => ['api/*'],`?

Comment: Indeed, it seems you pointed out the problem, now I just have "POST http://laravel.test/oauth/token 401 (Unauthorized)" as error message.

Comment: laravel-cors package has been abandoned because Laravel 7 comes with firs-placed cors support. However, even it comes, I still get the error. Someone please help me out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422229/any-reason-why-pre-build-cors-policy-configuration-not-functioning-in-laravel-7

Comment: Can someone please post the code that solves the issue here.

Comment: In recent Laravel projects, make sure `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors` middleware is enabled in `Kernel.php`.

Answer (score 3):

This in a solution that worked for me in the AuthServiceProviders.php file but it is not aesthetically correct: add the api prefix, so that `config/cors` does its job, don't forget to add it `use Illuminate\Support\ Facades\Route;`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
            Passport::routes();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by editing `config/cors.php` and adding `'oauth/*'` to `paths` array in this line:

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'oauth/*'],
```

Then clear cache by running `php artisan cache:clear` in terminal.

> Note: `config/cors.php` file exists in modern version of Laravel (after 2020)