# Any reason why pre-build cors policy configuration not functioning in Laravel 7 application?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex, django-cors-headers

I made a "post" request using axios to the Laravel back-end application. It always throws these errors

after submitting the form :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'mydomain' (redirected from 'mydomain') from origin 'mydomain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

before submitting the form :

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response mydomain with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

what I have done so far:

cors.php ( config file in laravel )

```
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*','web/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [
          'Cache-Control',
    'Content-Language',
    'Content-Type',
    'Expires',
    'Last-Modified',
    'Pragma', 
  ],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

Allow origin and the paths had been changed.

vue js axios request

```
const result = await this.callApi('post','/user/login', this.data)
```

callApi method

```
async callApi(method,url,data){

            try {
                
                //axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] ='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
                
                 // Send a POST request
                  return await axios({
                        method: method,
                        url: url,
                        data: data
                    });
            } catch (e) {
                return e.response
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the viewers.
"composer update" command has solved the problem.